# How do i access in variables in gradle buildscript block

Tags: gradle

I'm using this plugin https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nu.studer.credentials, for encrypting username and password for my private nexus repository.

Buildscript block looks like this

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "http://my.privaterepo.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'nu.studer:gradle-credentials-plugin:1.0.1'
        classpath 'com.private.plugin:Pipeline:0.4.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'nu.studer.credentials'

project.ext.usrname = credentials.uname
project.ext.passwd = credentials.passwd
```

To access my private nexus, i need to pass username and password to the **maven** . How can i achieve that using the plugin, considering buildscript block executes even before the plugins are initialized.

My end goal is to not have username and password saved as clear text in any file. Any other ideas are also welcome.